# Number of bytes to encode a signed integer

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to derive an algorithm to get the number of minimum bytes required to represent a signed integer. This is my current logic.

```
int exponent = -163;
std::uint8_t exponent_bytes = static_cast<std::uint8_t>((std::log2(abs(exponent)) / 8.0) + 1));
```

For eg, to encode -163, 2 bytes are required, but this gives only 1.

Comment: If you are using 2s complement representation, then you'll also need 2 bytes for +163, presumably.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, the algorithm fails for positive also - updated the question.

Comment: So, what's the problem? are you asking for the correct algorithm?

Comment: So just use `abs(exponent*2)` instead of `abs(exponent)`?

Comment: Use of `std::log2` is going to be subject to rounding errors in edge cases. You should use integer arithmetic only (which would also likely be more efficient)

Comment: @john Can you suggest an algorithm using only integer arithmetic in this case?

Comment: `int exponent` is also a bit limiting. I want to compute PI to 3'141'592'653'589'793'238 places.

Comment: Subtract `std::countl_zero(abs(x))` from the number of bits total and add 2. Then divide by the bits in `uint8_t`. Note: for large numbers using `uint8_t` as storage is inefficient. You want `uint32_t` or even 16/64 byte aligned storage for really large numbers.

Comment: @FaisalM Essentially you want the index of the leftmost 1-bit in your integer (or equivalently the number of leading zeros). A simple loop could get you that, but so can fancier suggestions like `countl_zero` if that is available on your platform.